# How to fix redirect_uri_mismatch the redirect URI OAuth Google

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am getting this error when I try to access the google calendar api

error:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:37461/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/$%7Byour_client_id%7D?project=$%7Byour_project_number%7D)

that port mentioned above `http://localhost:37461/` always changes.

And this is how I have set my `credentials.json`

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "<id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "stunning-surge-291419",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "***",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:3000/create"],
    "javascript_origins": ["http://localhost:3000"]
  }
}
```

And this is the `python` I am using to list the events in:

```
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

CREDENTIALS_FILE = "credentials.json"


def get_calendar_service():
   creds = None

   if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
       with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
           creds = pickle.load(token)
   # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
   if not creds or not creds.valid:
       if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
           creds.refresh(Request())
       else:
           flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
               CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)
           creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

       # Save the credentials for the next run
       with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
           pickle.dump(creds, token)

   service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
   return service
```

```
from createevent import get_calendar_service

def main():
   service = get_calendar_service()
   # Call the Calendar API
   print('Getting list of calendars')
   calendars_result = service.calendarList().list().execute()

   calendars = calendars_result.get('items', [])

   if not calendars:
       print('No calendars found.')
   for calendar in calendars:
       summary = calendar['summary']
       id = calendar['id']
       primary = "Primary" if calendar.get('primary') else ""
       print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (summary, id, primary))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

And I have set the redirect urls in the console as well:

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: In your case, how about modifying the redirect URL from `http://localhost:3000/create` to `http://localhost:3000` and the script is modified from `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` to `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=3000)`. By the way, from your `credentials.json` and the image, it seems that `http://localhost` is not saved. So when you modified the redirect URL, please click the save button. Please be careful this. If this comment was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Did @Tanaike's suggestion work for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

actually you can specify the port for the redirection uri to be fixed so that you will be redirected to the right url, in your case you have been redirected to http://localhost:37461/ `:37461` this number is randomized when you don't specify a specific port, as @Tanaike mentions you will need to fix the port to 3000 as shown in your screenshot.
`creds = flow.run_local_server(port=3000)`